Python - TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
I have working on different problems on 'countries.json' data. So now I need to find the country with the smallest area. so I've loaded the countries data to 'country_data'. But some of the data does not have 'area'. so its returning 'None' when I try to iterate and find minimum area.I need to avoid returning of 'None'
I have getting the following error:
File "path/countries.json", line 70, in <module>
    smallest_country = min(country_data, key=get_area)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

This is my code
def get_area(c):
    if c.get("area") is not None:
        return c.get("area")

smallest_country = min(country_data, key=get_area)
print(smallest_country.get("name"))


get_area returns the area key if it has any, or nothing otherwise. So, it's doing the same as just c.get('area') would do by itself. What do you want to do in this case? Either return some other comparable value, or filter out all areas with None first…?

Your get_area is pretty much useless. What do you think happens if c.get("area") IS None?

Returning some other value but None, e.g. 0 or +/-inf wont work either; it will fail for either the min or max case. Instead, you should filter out countries that do not have a size, e.g. smallest_country = min((c for c in country_data if get_area(c) is not None), key=get_area, default=None)

Return 0 is either trivially the right thing to do, or absolutely the wrong thing to do, depending on why a country is allowed to be missing an area attribute in the first place.

The problem with get_area(): If c.get("area") is None, the function does not return the area. In Python, it means returning None implicitly.
What you want is to filter out those countries which does not have area:
smallest_country = min(
    country['area'] for country in country_data if "area" in country
)

The above does two things at once:

It filters out those countries which does not have "area", and
It finds the minimum area

Update
It was my bad. The OP wanted the name of the smallest country, so here is the corrected code:
smallest_country = min(
    (country for country in country_data if "area" in country),
    key=lambda country: country["area"],
)
print(smallest_country["name"])

An alternative to using lambda is to use operator.itemgetter:
import operator

smallest_country = min(
    (country for country in country_data if "area" in country),
    key=operator.itemgetter("area"),
)
print(smallest_country["name"])


OP was interested in the name of the country with the smallest area…

I appreciate the comment, @deceze
